# How can I remove a deprecated version of a specific API resource from a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

When the storage version of a Kubernetes API resource changes, is it still necessary to manually read and write back resources as describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#upgrading-to-a-different-api-version) or does the apiserver now deal with this automatically?

For example, if I wanted to remove the [deprecated](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/12/kubernetes-19-workloads-expanded-ecosystem/) `extensions/v1beta1` version of deployments from my cluster and migrate to `apps/v1` would it be enough to specify `--storage-versions=extensions=apps/v1` on the apiserver and then ‘wait for a bit’ before setting something like `---runtime-config=api/all=true,extensions/v1beta1/deployments=false`? Or would I have to use the [update-storage-objects.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/update-storage-objects.sh) script after setting `--storage-versions=extensions=apps/v1`?

Additionally, would specifying `--storage-versions=extensions=apps/v1` cause any issues for ingress resources that still use API version `extensions/v1beta1` but have no conversion to `apps/v1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended method for doing this is still in flux. Removing API versions is currently prohibited: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52185

Answer (score 0):

> does the apiserver now deal with this automatically?

No, the api-server does not do it automatically, you need to do it manually.

Regarding the upgrade between API versions, all necessary steps are described in the official documentation:

> This is an infrequent event, but it requires careful management. There
>
> is a sequence of steps to upgrade to a new API version.
>
> 1. Turn on the new API version.
> 2. Upgrade the cluster’s storage to use the new version.
> 3. Upgrade all config files. Identify users of the old API version endpoints.
> 4. Update existing objects in the storage to new version by running `cluster/update-storage-objects.sh`.
> 5. Turn off the old API version.

Step 4 is not only about storage but also about all resources related to the old version which you have in the cluster.

> Additionally, would specifying --storage-versions=extensions=apps/v1 cause any issues for ingress resources that still use API version extensions/v1beta1 but have no conversion to apps/v1?

Versioning of each type of resource is independent. Storage and Ingress are different resources so there are no relations between their versions and different versions should not affect them in any way.

Comment: I linked out to the those steps in the question itself - I heard that read and writing back was no longer necessary, hence the question, but I guess that is not the case. As for your final point, Storage isn't a resource at all so I'm not quite sure what you mean by that - but in relation to my question (with deployments and ingress resources) they were originally in the same group (extensions) so the specified storage versions are linked. I think my question is answered with https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52185 however

Answer (score -1):

Im usually upgrading the cluster with a new API version then upgrade the config files but not removing the old API. Only once I had to remove a old API version due to a bug. You can do this by running `kubectl get apiservice` to list all available versions then `kubectl delete apiservice some_api` and you don't have to set any other flag.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - deleting the `v1beta1.extensions` apiservice resource still allows me to create deployments of that version as well as ingress resources